# Как ждать появления элемента

Tags: android, тестирование, espresso

Тестирую андроид-приложение с эспрессо. Тест проходит через обращение к серверу, которое может затянуться. Как сделать так, чтобы тест подождал, пока появится нужный view на экране?

Answer (score 1):

Раннее ужа давал ответ на этот вопрос здесь - [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616822/211117). Вы можете сначала запустить просто приложение, чтобы посмотреть сколько примерно ожидает элемент приложение и уже потом выставить примерный Sleep(в примере указано время в секундах). 1500 - 1.5 секунды.