# Espresso тест на ожидание

Tags: java, android, kotlin, espresso

Есть следующий тест, который при переходе в форму логина, вводит некорректные данные, в ответ на которые ему выводится дилоговое окно с текстом "Warning":

```
@Test
fun signInUserWithInvalidPassword() {
    goToSignIn()
    AcceptanceHelper.updateValidationTextView(R.string.ui_data_attribute_email, VALID_EMAIL)
    AcceptanceHelper.updateValidationTextView(R.string.ui_data_attribute_password, "987654321")
    AcceptanceHelper.clickOnButtonInLayout(R.id.mainSignButton, R.string.common_signin_button_text, R.id.inputLayout)
    onView(isRoot()).perform(AcceptanceHelper.waitId(R.id.titleTextView, 5000))
    AcceptanceHelper.checkTextView(R.id.titleTextView, "Warning")
```

Проблема в том что тест падает на строчке:

```
        onView(isRoot()).perform(AcceptanceHelper.waitId(R.id.titleTextView, 5000))
```

Мол открывается во фрагменте диалог, элементы которого он не находит. 
А вот и собственно сам метод `waitId`:

```
fun waitId(id: Int, millis: Long): ViewAction {
    return object : ViewAction {
        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return isRoot()
        }

        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "wait for a specific view with id <$id> during $millis millis."
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle()
            val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val endTime = startTime + millis
            val viewMatcher = withId(id)

            do {
                for (child in TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(view)) {
                    // found view with required ID
                    if (viewMatcher.matches(child)) {
                        return
                    }
                }

                uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(50)
            } while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime)

            // timeout happens
            throw PerformException.Builder()
                    .withActionDescription(this.description)
                    .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                    .withCause(TimeoutException())
                    .build()
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно кто то сталкивался, и может подсказать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можете воспользоваться вместо вашего метода следующим способом:

```
SystemClock.sleep(5000)
```

или

```
Thread.sleep(1500);
```

Также можно упростить Ваш метод и проставлять значения таймаута заранее:

```
 fun waitFor(id: Int, millis: Long): ViewAction {
    return object : ViewAction {
        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return isRoot()
        }

        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "Wait for a specific view with $id during $millis millis."
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle()
        }
    }
}
```

Но не стоит забывать, что это не самые лучшие варианты, так как Вам придётся постоянно ожидать n-ое кол-во времени. Лучше всего загружать нужные Вам элементы, в данном случае текст, который вы хотите проверить сразу, как только загрузился диалог.
Поэтому попробуйте еще такой вариант как [IdlingResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingResource.html), а в качестве примера попробуйте разобраться перейдя по ссылке [здесь](http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/espresso-custom-idling-resource.html).

Comment: Спасибо подошло, сейчас вот пытаюсь разобраться с последним вариантом. Не овсем просто разобраться пока.

Answer (score 0):

Можно конечно использовать Idling Resource, но он очень сложен для новичка и требуют обязательно лезть в продуктовый код. Вот я считаю лучшее решение из предложенных:

```
public static ViewAction waitDisplayed(final int viewId, final long millis) {
return new ViewAction() {
    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return isRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "wait for a specific view with id <" + viewId + "> has been displayed during " + millis + " millis.";
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view) {
        uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long endTime = startTime + millis;
        final Matcher<View> matchId = withId(viewId);
        final Matcher<View> matchDisplayed = isDisplayed();

        do {
            for (View child : TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(view)) {
                if (matchId.matches(child) && matchDisplayed.matches(child)) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(50);
        }
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime);

        // timeout happens
        throw new PerformException.Builder()
                .withActionDescription(this.getDescription())
                .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                .withCause(new TimeoutException())
                .build();
    }
};
```

}

потом в коде пишите вот так:

```
@Test
fun shouldBeAbleToLoadList() {
    onView(isRoot()).perform(waitDisplayed(R.id.recycler_view, 5000));
}
```

ссылка [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482891/espresso-test-fails-due-to-data-binding/58488181#58488181)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Исправил по Вашим рекомендациям.